# can i add indendented code in a js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indentation

Below is link to js code

non indented :
http://jsfiddle.net/bsr1/ucg6v1v0/

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">Focus Shifted Here</div>';
alert("*");
```

indented
http://jsfiddle.net/bsr1/1dtrz0au/

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">
            Focus Shifted Here
        </div>';
alert("*");
```

I know 2nd one results in an js error.Is there nay way i can indent my js code without erorr

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1dtrz0au/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1dtrz0au/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string cannot be declared across multiple lines.

**Option 1 - Concatenate:**

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">' + 
            'Focus Shifted Here' + 
        '</div>';
```

**Option 2 - Escape the newline with a backslash:**

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">\
            Focus Shifted Here\
        </div>';
```

I would advise against option 2, since it relies on the right amount of whitespace after the `\`, and is not ideal for minification.

On the bright size, ES6 will introduce [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

Answer (score 1):

You can indent your JS code. Indeed, everyone will be happy if you do.

However, you cannot break a string into multiple lines like that.

You can cancel a line break in a string by having a backslash `\` as the last character:

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">\
            Focus Shifted Here\
        </div>';
```

If you also want the newline in the string, you must put it in explicitly:

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">\n\
            Focus Shifted Here\n\
        </div>';
```

You can also break up the string and assemble it from parts at runtime:

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">\n' +
            'Focus Shifted Here\n' +
        '</div>';
```

However, you cannot have an unescaped linebreak inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do for easy reading is:

`var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">'+
                  'Focus Shifted Here'+
               '</div>';
alert("*");`

Answer (score 0):

End with `\`

```
var dataAbc = '<div class="message7">\
            Focus Shifted Here\
        </div>';
alert("*");
```

Still, I don't think it's a good idea to insert (complicated) HTML structure in JS.

Comment: why -1 for this ans??

Answer (score -1):

Javascript doesn't have a here-document syntax. You can escape the literal newline, however, which comes close:

```
"foo \
bar"
```

Ref taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: why -1 for this ans????? Plz explain...